# React - Search & filter through a data set

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, event-handling, render

I have a react application that is fetching data from an express server. The fetch is fine, data is displaying properly, and the search feature is functioning correctly when the user input matches something in the data set. However, if the user then deletes out their input the data set will not return to the previous state and instead the user is forced to make a hard refresh.

How would I go about fixing this so that when the user deletes input (goes from "james" to "") the page filters back to all data?

```
function SearchForm({ data, setData }) {


  
  /*TRACK USER INPUT INTO SEARCH BOX*/
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  /*FRONT END: FILTER THROUH DATA TO FIND MATCHES TO SEARCH VALUE*/
  const searchVehicles = (data, searchValue) => {
    const searchedValue = searchValue.toUpperCase();
    const result = data.filter(
      (currenttable) =>
        currenttable.last_name.toUpperCase().includes(searchedValue) ||
        currenttable.first_name.toUpperCase().includes(searchedValue) ||
        currenttable.store.toUpperCase().includes(searchedValue)
    );

    if (searchValue) {
      setData(result);
      console.log(result);
    } else {
      setData(data)
    }
  };

  /*CALL THE FUNCTION WHEN INPUT IS ENETERED*/
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
    searchVehicles(data, event.target.value);
    console.log(searchValue)
  };

  /*RESET THE SEARCH BAR AND RENDER ALL DATA */
  const handleReset = () => {
    setSearchValue("");
  };

  /*OUTPUT */

  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="search">Search: </label>
      <input
        className="search-applicant"
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Search applicant or store"
        onChange={event => handleChange(event)}
        value={searchValue}
      ></input>
      <button className="search-btn" onClick={handleReset}>
        Refresh
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SearchForm;
```

Comment: Just at a quick glance why don't you use a hook ? 

useEffect(() => {
  setData(data.filter((currenttable) =>
        currenttable.last_name.toUpperCase().includes(searchedValue) ||
        currenttable.first_name.toUpperCase().includes(searchedValue) ||
        currenttable.store.toUpperCase().includes(searchedValue)))
}, [searchValue])

And you can remove the searchVehicle function and its calls altogether

EDIT: I forgot the toUpperCase calls but you get the idea

Comment: That cleaned things up and simplified the code but did not solve the main issue. As you delete out the form entry the page does not reset, it remains on the filtered version

Comment: I'll try to put together a quick demo when I get a chance to see if we can figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! So every time you filter you are modifying the original data. Here's what happens.

At first your component has `data` which (for example) is now ["a", "b", "c"]. Then you type "a", and it calls `setData` which changes the state to ["a"]. But you are modifying the original data so now data only has "a" in it and nothing else!

You can just change your component to NOT change the original data and just filter directly in your rendered elements

```
function SearchForm({ data }) {


/*TRACK USER INPUT INTO SEARCH BOX*/
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  /*CALL THE FUNCTION WHEN INPUT IS ENETERED*/
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  };

  /*RESET THE SEARCH BAR AND RENDER ALL DATA */
  const handleReset = () => {
    setSearchValue("");
  };

  /*OUTPUT */
  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="search">Search: </label>
      <input
        className="search-applicant"
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Search applicant or store"
        onChange={event => handleChange(event)}
        value={searchValue}
      />
      {data
        .filter(({ first_name}) => first_name.includes(searchValue)) /* or whatver filter you want*/
        .map(({first_name, last_name, store}) => <div key={store}>{`${first_name} ${last_name} => ${store}`}</div>)
      }
      <button className="search-btn" onClick={handleReset}>
        Refresh
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Or you can create a local copy of it (e.g. `const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(data)`, and you set your `filteredData` to be `data` with the filter applied but you never mutate data ever).

[See Example Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-roman-8d3y0)

Comment: Ah Thank you so much!